# Gravity Form Backend

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

Here is the issue im having. I would like the total price field to have a calculation. lets say if total > 600 then total = 600.
I got this done in the front end using js in html field. But once its submitted to paypal the condition does nothing.

here is the front end code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

gform.addFilter( 'gform_product_total', function(total, formId){
    //only apply logic to form ID 5
    if(formId != 5)
        return total;

    if(total > 600)
        total = 600;

    return total;
} );
```

THis works fine in the front end but it doesn't in the backend.

I need this to be translated to the back end in the theme function.php file using php. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the [gform_after_submission](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/) filter (php - should go in you theme functions.php file) thusly:

```
add_filter( "gform_after_submission_5", "calculationFunction", 10, 4 );
function calculationFunction( $entry, $lead, $field, $form ){
    if ( $entry[1] > 600 ){
      $entry[1] = 600;
    }
    return $form;
}
```

The _5 attached to the gform_after_submission will limit this function to form id 5 and $entry[1](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/) should be changed to the field id holding your 'total price'